# text based game item collection and randomizing villain location

Tags: python, pycharm

I've never posted on here so I'll do my best to format everything correctly. I am writing a text-based Python game for school that involves collecting items and a villain. The villain is designed to end the game if encountered. I wanted to randomize the villain's location between a 'window' and 'front door' option, making the end random chance if you win or lose. (see FIXME) Secondly, I was having trouble separating the text that displays when you enter a room and the text regarding collectibles. I was trying to make it so that once an item is collected the collectible text no longer displays as that item is no longer in the room after it is collected. I was having a lot of trouble with this under the comment #look around. Thank you in advance for the help :P

```
    rooms = {
'Outside': {'name': 'Outside', 'North': 'Dining Room',
                'text': 'You are outside and stare at the back door to the house.'},

'Dining Room': {'name': 'Dining Room', 'North': 'Living Room', 'contents': ['vase'],
               'West': 'Kitchen', 'text': 'You are in the dining room.', 'item_get': 'There is a vase in this room... It looks valuable.'},

'Kitchen': {'name': 'Kitchen', 'East': 'Dining Room', 'contents': 'Blender',
            'text': 'You are in the kitchen. There is a blender on the counter.'},

'Living Room': {'name': 'Living Room', 'South': 'Dining Room', 'East': 'Stairs', 'West': 'Bathroom', 'contents': ['TV'],
            'text': 'You are in the Living room. There is a TV on the wall.'},

'Bathroom': {'name': 'Bathroom', 'East': 'Living Room', 'contents': ['Candle'],
            'text': 'You are in the Bathroom. There is a candle on the counter.'},

'Stairs': {'name': 'Stairs', 'North': 'Hallway', 'West': 'Living Room',
           'text': 'You are in the stairway. There is a hallway at the top.'},

'Hallway': {'name': 'Hallway', 'East': 'Bedroom', 'West': 'Kids Bedroom',
            'text': 'You are in the hallway. There are bedrooms on either side of you.'},

'Bedroom': {'name': 'Bedroom', 'West': 'Hallway', 'contents': ['Jewelry'],
           'text': 'You are in the bedroom. There is jewelry on the dresser.'},

'Kids Bedroom': {'name': 'Kids Bedroom', 'East': 'Hallway', 'contents': ['Music box'],
            'text': 'You are in a kids bedroom. There is a music box on a shelf.'},
#FIXME: ESCAPE ROUTES
#is there a way to randomize where the villain will be between two exit options?
    }

    directions = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West']
    items = ['look around']
    look_around = ['item_get']
    currentRoom = rooms['Outside']
    carrying = []


    print('Hello. You are outside')

    while True:
        # display current location
        print()
        print(format(currentRoom['text']))
        # get input
        command = input('\nWhat next? ').strip()

# movement
if command in directions:
    if command in currentRoom:
        currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom[command]]
    else:
        print("You can't go that way.")

#look around
if command in items:
    if command in look_around:
        look_around = rooms[items[command]]
    else:
        print("There is nothing to see.")

# quit game
elif command.lower() in ('e', 'exit'):
    break

elif command.lower().split()[0] == 'get':
    item = command.lower().split()[1]
    if item in currentRoom['contents']:
        carrying.append(item)
        print('You stole the {}!'.format(currentRoom['contents']))
    else:
        print("That object is not in this room.")
```

Comment: Ask randint() for a random number, and based on that put the villain here or there. https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint As far as collectibles go? Rather than a `str`, more convenient to model each one as an object, perhaps an `enum`, with a descriptive attribute like "There is jewelry on the dresser" or "There is a music box on a shelf". Then you display the room text, loop through all objects currently in the room, and display the text for each of them. Quick! Implement it now, before you are eaten by a grue!